# Asciidoctor maven plugin is generating index.html with no read permissions

Tags: java, spring, maven, asciidoctor, maven-jar-plugin

Im creating an index.htm file with the asciidoctor-maven-plugin:2.2.2 and I get a build error, because the created file has no read permissions. `mvn clean install`

[image: build failure stacktrace]

[image: file permissions]

[image: pom.xml]

`mvn clean install` works on other machines. I am on a M1 Macbook Pro. I have tried to change Java version (currently using 17 Zulu) and Maven version (3.8.6), but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`asciidoctor` internally uses `JRuby`, which in turn had related issue when running on `M1`: [Wrong file mode/permission when opening/creating a new file [Apple Silicon, arm64, aarch64]](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/issues/6983)

according to [Update JNR for Apple Silicon varargs support #6985](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/pull/6985) you need to move on `JRuby 9.2.21.0`:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.asciidoctor</groupId>
    <artifactId>asciidoctor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jruby</groupId>
            <artifactId>jruby</artifactId>
            <!-- <artifactId>jruby-complete</artifactId> -->
            <version>9.2.21.0</version>
        </dependency>
....
```

Answer (score 0):

you are not including your generated files directory to the classpath.
try to add this ,

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>${project.build.directory}/classes/generated-docs/api-gateway</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    ...
</build>
```

${basedir}/src/main/resources ==> chage it with the right directory

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work